# What is the procedure for customizing device metadata package for the "System" (PC) icon in Windows 10 Devices & Printers?

Tags: windows-10, icons, metadata, authoring

I have been customising the icons displayed in the Windows 10 "Devices & Printers" folder to display more representative images for my devices by using the Windows 10 Device Metadata Authoring Wizard.

It has been possible to achieve this (by trial and error) for all displayed icons except the main "System" icon representing the PC itself and that displayed for the WiFi Router (which is greyed out).

The process steps in the Authoring Wizard are different for the "System Icon" which appears to follow a completely different process as the "Device only metadata" generates the following message "Non-OEM devices must not have "Computer" or one of its subcategories as Primary Category. Choosing "Computer:Desktop" as the primary category will change the package type to a "OEM/PC Internal Metadata package", which might lead to some data being lost."

Can anyone suggest how to proceed for an "OEM/PC Internal Metadata package"?